# C# - Menu Strip Query

Tags: c#, menu, strip, menustrip

I have two questions regarding the windows form menu strip:

**1. How to force the form to always show the helper keys?**
Currently the letter underlines are displayed only if the Alt key is pressed.

**2. What is the command to cause a menu to drop down?**
Usually a menu drops down after the user clicks the menu button or navigates it with the keyboard, but I want to cause a menu to drop down by pressing an interface button and I can't figure out how to do it. I tried fiddling the DropDown property, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With ToolStripMenuItem there are three properties you need to look at:
   ShortcutKeyDisplayString
   ShortcutKeys
   ShowShortcutKeys

   - Although the three apply to the root menu item, say File or Help, you will not be able to see the short cuts, however you should be able to enable the ShortcutKeys, set ShowShortcutKeys to true and without modifying ShortcutKeyDisplayStringhave them appear next to sub ToolStripMenuItem's.
2. The method you are looking for on ToolStripMenuItem is [ShowDropDown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.showdropdown.aspx), executing this method will drop down the menu.

Example:

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)FileMenu.Items[0]).ShowDropDown();
```

Comment: Thank you, Moses. You are right about the ShowDropDown() method.

Regarding the first query, I think I am not able to force-display letter underlines as that may be controlled by the system settings only.

Comment: As for the helper keys, I thought you were referring to the ALT+D that appears to the right of menu items, not the underline indicating the accelerator key.

Comment: I noticed the properties you mentioned in the Properties window when I was designing the form, but yeah, I was referring to the underlines indicating the Alt key combination.

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK, it is not *easily* possible to do that in C#. The easiest way is to change the Windows settings. On Windows 7:

   - Go to Control panel
   - *Ease of Access Center*
   - *Make the Keyboard easier to use*
   - Check *Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys*.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Otiel. I know about that setting as well, but I was looking for a way to force displaying the underline because I'm working on an application which will be distributed to other users, and I would want them to see the underlines without having to change any system settings.